# Dynamic update of stringview

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to update a `ListView` by replacing the `QStringList` (residing in a C++ object) that acts as a QML `ListView` model. I replace the contents of the model `QStringList`, but the `ListView` display dependent on this model does not change to reflect the new contents. Here is the code:

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: frame
    objectName: "root"
    height: 400;  width: 600

    signal vendorChangedSignal(string vendortext)

ListView {
    width: 100; height: 100

    model: ModelCollection.cbModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 25
        width: 100
        Text { text: modelData }
    }
}
Button {
    x: 20;  y:300
    text: "Change"
    onClicked: {
        frame.vendorChangedSignal("x")
    }
}

} // Rectangle
```

and the C++ class:

```
class ModelClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList cbModel READ cbModel WRITE setCbModel NOTIFY cbModelChanged)

    public:
        ModelClass();
        ~ModelClass();

        static ModelClass *instance();

        QString vendorName;
        QString productName;

        QStringList ProductList2();
        QStringList m_comboList;
        Q_INVOKABLE QStringList cbModel();
        void setCbModel(QStringList cbModel);
        void printList(QStringList plist);

    public slots:
        void newVendorSlot(const QString &vendortext);

    signals:
        void cbModelChanged();

    private:
        static ModelClass *m_instance;
        QStringList productList2;
};
```

and the C++ implementation methods:

```
void printList(QStringList plist);

ModelClass *ModelClass::m_instance = NULL;

ModelClass::ModelClass() {
    m_instance = this;
}

ModelClass::~ModelClass() {
    m_instance = NULL;
}

QStringList ModelClass::cbModel() {
    qDebug() << "combomodel() called";
    printList(m_comboList);
    return(m_comboList);
}

void ModelClass::setCbModel(QStringList cbModel) {
    m_comboList = cbModel;
    qDebug() << "set comboModel() called" << m_comboList[0] << "..." <<     m_comboList[3];
}

void ModelClass::newVendorSlot(const QString &msgText) {
    vendorName = msgText;
    () << "C++ newVendorSlot: vendorName:" << vendorName;
    setCbModel(ProductList2());
}

QStringList ModelClass::ProductList2() { // This is only for test purposes
    productList2.clear();
    productList2 << "beans" << "cabbage" << "carrots" << "beetroot" << "potatos";
    return(productList2);
}

void ModelClass::printList(QStringList plist) {  // Only for test purposes.
    QString string1;
    foreach(string1,plist)
        qDebug() << string1;
}
```

lastly, the C++ main code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    ModelClass ModelList;
    QQuickView view;

    QStringList dataList1;  // Create QML model
    dataList1.append("oranges");
    dataList1.append("peaches");
    dataList1.append("bananas");
    dataList1.append("grapes");

    ModelList.setCbModel(dataList1);  // store model in object ModelList

    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext(); // Create QML handle for model:
    ctxt->setContextProperty("ModelCollection", &ModelList);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));

    QObject *dcSelectPanel = view.rootObject(); // Connect QML signal to ModelList slot
    QObject::connect(dcSelectPanel,SIGNAL(vendorChangedSignal(QString)),
                     &ModelList,SLOT(newVendorSlot(QString)));

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

That produces this console output:

> set comboModel() called "oranges" ... "grapes"
>   combomodel() called
>   "oranges"
>   "peaches"
>   "bananas"
>   "grapes"

When the QML button is pressed, this is shown:

> C++ newVendorSlot: vendorName: "x"
>   set comboModel() called "beans" ... "beetroot"

indicating that the `QStringList` substitution was ok. However the `StringView` display does not chnage and still shows names of fruit.

Does anyone have a suggestion at all?

Comment: Your code has a compilation error: `() << "C++ newVendorSlot: vendorName:" << vendorName;`

Answer (score 1):

[Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qstringlist-based-model) says:

> **Note:** There is no way for the view to know that the contents of a QStringList have changed. If the QStringList changes, it will be necessary to reset the model by calling QQmlContext::setContextProperty() again.

I would recommend using a `QAbstractItemModel`-based model to avoid having to do this, but if you want to use `QStringList` instead, you'll need to store a pointer to the QML context in `ModelClass` so that you can set the context property.